# How can you download multiple photos from photo google?

Tags: google-photos

First I want to clarify that **I am not talking about google drive**.

I would like to download the photos I have in `photos.google.com`

I searched and the resources explain either

- How to download *one* photo
- How to download *all* photos

but I cannot find how can I select several photos and download them

When I try to select them , each time I click, a single photo is selected

How can I download *several* photos from google photos?

Answer (score 1):

hover over the picture and click the check mark top left of the picture, light gray in colour and mid opacity.

[image: checkmark]

After making your selection click on the three dots at the top right of the page and click download or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on your keyboard.

[image: three dots]
[image: download button]